# Using Python-Flask-MongoDB with Geolocation field running on App Engine?

Tags: python, geolocation, mongodb

I'm trying to write an app which would act as a address caching API, so basically it needs to store addresses (geolocations) and later on I could query on a random address and radius and get all the cached locations within the radius of that point.

I prefer to use Python on Google Appengine, I tried DataStore GeoPT but to do such a query it would end up being really expensive and not really efficient.
So I started reading about [MongoDB Geospatial Query](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-geospatial/), $near option. But apparently there is no support for any Python-MongoDB-GAE that also supports GeoLocation fields e.g [Flask-MongoEngine](https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine/blob/master/docs/index.rst#not-currently-supported-field-types).

Does anyone know a solution to this or even another stack to work on which makes this implementation feasible?

Comment: I ended up using NodeJS on heroku to write this app. not sure if the python issue is resolved by now.